# Form that logs in to a website?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

If there is a website and I want to write a form that logs me in, how can I do it?

This form logs me to stack overflow

```
<form method="post" action="https://stackoverflow.com/users/login">
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="myemail">
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="mypassword">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I want to do so on [this website](http://forums.heroesofnewerth.com/index.php), but the script doesn't work for some reason.

```
<form method="post" action="http://forums.heroesofnewerth.com/login.php?do=login/">
    <input type="hidden" name="vb_login_username" value="myusr">
    <input type="hidden" name="vb_login_password" value="mypass">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Any idea why?

Ok, it worked I had to send more data.

```
<form method="post" action="http://forums.heroesofnewerth.com/login.php" onsubmit="md5hash(vb_login_password, vb_login_md5password, vb_login_md5password_utf, 0)">
    <input type="hidden" name="vb_login_username" value="usr">
    <input type="hidden" name="vb_login_password" value="pwd">
    <input type="hidden" name="do" value="login">
    <input type="hidden" name="vb_login_md5password" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="vb_login_md5password_utf" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="s" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="securitytoken" value="guest">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://forums.heroesofnewerth.com/index.php">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Because they most likely have features in place to prevent it?

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to login everywhere as long as I have username and password?

Comment: No, some sites has features to prevent that kind of access.

Comment: the referral page check is one kind of basic security control. Probably they don't accept post requests from an external domain

Comment: What kind of features? What's the difference between sending data through my form with post and their form?

Comment: Why the heck I get so many minuses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of websites on the internet (not nearly enough though) have protection in place that prevents sites other then their own to post forms (log in for example) to their site. A site that does not have this protection is vulnerable to:

- Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

This is a major security risk that allows phishing sites to log you in to the actual website while catching your login details and a whole lot of other nasty stuff.

There could also be other protection in place to prevent you from sending a request.

Try to see if there are any API's available instead for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Wouldn't the API do the same thing?

Comment: There might not even be a API method in place that allows you to do this. If there is it allows the developers more control of the requests you send and monitor this.